# Factor of two when finding the number of AM stations which can be fit into a bandwidth given the highest modulating frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency

> How many AM broadcast stations can be accommodated in a 100 KHZ bandwidth if the highest modulating frequency of carrier is 5 kHZ?
>
> Ans.
> Solve by using the formula:$$ \text{total band width}= 2 ( \text{number of stations}) \text{carrier frequency}$$

Why does a multiplicative factor of two come in the above equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In amplitude modulation we have a carrier wave:

$$ c(t) = C \sin(\omega_c t) $$

and a signal:

$$ m(t) = M \sin(\omega_s t) $$

And we multiply the carrier by $1 + m(t)$ to produce the radio wave:

$$ R(t) = (1 + M\sin(\omega_s t)) C \sin(\omega_c t) $$

And this splits into:

$$ R(t) = C \sin(\omega_c t) + CM \sin(\omega_c t) \sin(\omega_s t) $$

The first term is just the original wave, $c(t)$, while we can use a trig identity to write the second term as:

$$ \sin(\omega_s t)\sin(\omega_c t) = \tfrac12[\cos((\omega_c + \omega_s)t) - \cos((\omega_c - \omega_s)t)] $$

So the amplitude modulation has caused two new frequencies $\omega_c \pm \omega_s$ to appear as well as the original carrier frequency $\omega_c$. That means the bandwith of the modulated wave, i.e. the highest frequency minus the lowest frequency, is $2\omega_s$. That's where the factor of $2$ comes from.

Comment: If we have two consecutive bands, can one band's upper frequency be another's lower frequency?

Comment: @Buraian in principle yes, though in practice radio stations leave a bit of extra space to avoid problems with stations interfering with each other. I don't know the exact details - you'd have to ask an engineer.

Comment: @JohnRennie The answer to the question which is asking about overlap of sidebands is "only the "tails" can overlap depending on the strength of the two signals?

Comment: @Farcher AM stations use a low pass filter to make sure the sideband frequency does not exceed the available bandwidth. Googling suggests that 5KHz is a typical cut-off frequency. But you'd have to ask a radio engineer exactly how the cutoff they use is related to the bandwidth they have been allocated.

Comment: And this is one reason why Single Side Band (SSB) is used...