# Why does amplitude modulated wave take the frequency of a carrier signal when passed through air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, radio-frequency

> If a message signal of frequency $f_m$ is amplitude modulated with a carrier signal of frequency $f_c$ and radiated through an antenna, the wavelength of the corresponding signal in air is
>
> ans: $\frac{c}{f_c}$

I know that the amplitude modulated radio wave is given as:

$$R(t) = \left[ 1+ \sin( \omega_s t) \right] C \sin(\omega_c t)$$

By trig identites , we see in the above function contains frequency of $\omega_c, \omega_c + \omega_s, \omega_c - \omega_s$ [refer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/652740/236734), then why is it that only the carrier frequency is considered for wavelength calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK AM radio frequencies are around a megahertz and the signal bandwidth is around 5kHz so in effect the frequency is the carrier plus or minus $0.5\%$. To a very good approximation the frequency of the wave is just the carrier frequency.

Comment: Oh, then the answer shouldn't be exact then

Comment: @Buraian, the velocity of the wave in air is not exactly *c* either (it's about 0.03% lower).